# AppDateTimePicker close after choosing date in Modal on Vuexy theme

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am building Vue.js application using Vuexy theme.
I have a datetimepicker in a modal. My problem is that when I click date in datetimepicker component, it doesn't stay open and the modal is closed too.

If you have any question or need codebase, please let me know.

Code is:

```
<AppDateTimePicker
   v-model="delDate"
   :rules="[requiredValidator]"
   label="Delivery Date"
   placeholder="Delivery Date"
   @input="onDateInput"
   persistentPlaceholder
/>
```

I can't find any solution to solve it.